# can't get any hits from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently upgraded to ES 6 and I can't get any search results.  If I go and look at a single record in ES, I see the text is there:

{"_index":"cases","_type":"case","_id":"5a686d6b19a13757ac2c54d7","_version":2,"found":true,"_source":{"data":{"Basic Information":{"Project Type":"OCW","Code":"0124-RHY","Title":"Broward Investigative Case Management","Letter Of Intent Due":"","Question Due":"02/02/2018","Proposal Due":"02/14/2018","Rfp Doc":"                                    Scope of Work\n\n        TEC2114786P1 – Investigative Management System\n\n\nPROFILE OF THE BROWARD OFFICE OF THE INSPECTOR GENERAL:\n\nThe Broward Office of the Inspector General (OIG) is a criminal justice agency that was created\n\nin November 2010. The OIG functions as anindependent watchdog for over 1.8 million residents\nof Broward County. Its authority encomp     asses more than 25,000 employees, and over 450\n\nseparate divisions and departments of govern     ment. In addition, the OIG has oversight\nresponsibility for more than 170 elected offici als including county commissioners, mayors, vice\n\nmayors, city commissioners, and town council me mbers, as well as more than 36,000 registered\nvendors who provide goods or services to the county and municipalities.\n\n\nThe OIG has the authority to investigate violations of state and federal statutes and codes, county\nand municipal ordinances and...

However, If I run this query, I get no hits:

```
"query":{
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match":{
                        "text": "criminal"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I had to overhaul my queries because of the changes between 2 and 6 (this is a big upgrade) and I'm just trying to get full text searching to work.  Can anyone see what's wrong with my query?

UPDATE: I figured it out, you have to use a query_string query:

```
"must": {
    "query_string":{
        "query": "criminal"
    }
 }
```

Comment: `text` is the name of the field? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html might work better for multiple fields

Comment: no, i thought if you use "text" that means to search all fields.  Isn't there a text analyzer that searches all fields?

Comment: The [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query searches all fields by default. `_all` might also work as a field name

Comment: thanks for your help @apokryfos see my update